# How to show the following determinant inequality problem

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, determinant

Let $A\in M_2(\Bbb{R})$ be such that  $\det\,A\geq0$. Show that $$\det(A^n+I_2)+\det(A^n-I_2)\geq\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\left(\det\,A+1\right)^n$$

I have shown that $$\det(A^n+I_2)+\det(A^n-I_2)\geq2((\det A)^n+1)$$ From this how I can proceed?

Comment: So you've reduced it to a 1-diml calculus problem, prove that for $x\geqslant 0$ we have $f(x):=2^{n-1}(1+x^n)-(1+x)^n\geqslant 0$.

Comment: And as far as I see $f$ has a single minimum value of $0$ at $x=1$.